# no output from function after cout another string before

Tags: c++

to refresh my rusty c++ knowledge i have created a small program.

however, a small problem occurs. I get the output of a commando into a vector. afterwards I output the content of the vector again.

if i now output something before the output of the vector content, then interestingly the output of the vector no longer appears. Why is this so?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const vector<string>& execv(const char* cmd);
void output(const vector<string>& vec);


int main() {

    const vector<string>& result = execv("net user %USERNAME%");

    int _numlines = result.size();

    // if i uncomment the following line there's no output from 'output'
    //cout << _numlines << " lines had been found: " << endl;

    output(result);

    return 0;
}

void output(const vector<string>& vec)
{
    for(const string& line : vec)
        cout << line;
}


const vector<string>& execv(const char* cmd)
{
    array<char, 128> buffer;
    vector<string> result;
    //string result;
    unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&pclose)> pipe(_popen(cmd, "r"), _pclose);

    if(!pipe)
    {
        throw runtime_error("_popen() failed!");
    }

    while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr)
    {
        result.push_back(buffer.data());
    }

    const vector<string>& _res = result;

    return _res;
}
```

Comment: Your `execv` returns a dangling reference, reading from it causes undefined behavior. The function should return by value.

Comment: `execv` returns a reference to a local variable. That variable is destroyed when the function returns, leaving the reference dangling. Any attempt by the caller to use that reference exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others say, don't return reference to local variable.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc11d5985a70ae07)**

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using Strings = std::vector<std::string>;

Strings execv(std::string cmd);
void    output(const Strings& vec);

int main() {
    auto result = execv("net user %USERNAME%");

    std::cout << result.size() << " lines had been found: " << std::endl;
    output(result);
}

void output(const std::vector<std::string>& vec)
{
    for (auto& line : vec)
        std::cout << line;
}

#include <stdexcept>

Strings execv(std::string cmd)
{
    Strings result;
    std::array<char, 128> buffer;
    //string result;
    std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&pclose)> pipe(::popen(cmd.c_str(), "r"), ::pclose);

    if (!pipe) {
        throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    }

    while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr)
    {
        result.push_back(buffer.data());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Which on my Linux machine prints

```
Invalid command: net rap user %USERNAME%
4 lines had been found:
Usage:
net rap user add             Add specified user
net rap user info            List domain groups of specified user
net rap user delete          Remove specified user
```

Comment: Yes, it works with that, thank you.

But aren't we using a copy of the string vector now? I actually wanted to use a reference so that the data doesn't have to be copied, or is my approach wrong here?